# Add Attendees to Meeting

Tags: webex

I want to schedule a Webex Meeting. When seeking to invite attendees,the Attendees text box is asking me to type in email addresses. There must be a way to select from my list of contacts. I have a distribution list defined in contacts that I could use.
How do I do this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You‘re using the web interface to schedule a meeting. The web interface doesn’t have access to your contacts, so have to type in or copy/paste all addresses.

Alternatively, you can schedule meetings from MS Outlook or possibly similar products. Inside Outlook you have Access to your normal contacts, which might be what you want.

Note: Webex web interface remembers emails entered, so next time you don’t have to type them in manually again.

Comment: I've since discovered that access to contacts is available through the classic view, as opposed to the modern view.